# Does your wudu break if a dog licks you?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, wudu, dogs, self-purification

I know that you're supposed to wash the part of your body where a dog has licked seven times. But do you also have to redo your wudu?

Answer (score 0):

Salam and Alhamdulillah,

No. Touching things are impure does not break wudu. If a dog licks you, then you are still in the state of wudu all you need to do is wash the area the dog licked you 7 times and one of these times being with soil or soap as the Prophet (saw) said that if a dog licks the utensil of any of you then discard what is in it and wash the utensil 7 times and one of the times being with soil. Many scholars agree that soap can be used in replacement for soil. However touching things impure does not break wudu. The things that break wudu are clear such as peeing, pooping, passing gas or wind, deep sleep and eating camel meat and according to some scholars touching the private parts. According to one Hadith, laughing out loud during salah will also break wudu but scholars different on its authenticity and some scholars were of the view that this Hadith is not strong or authentic and that it is a weak Hadith. There are a couple of Hadiths that state to do wudu after drinking camel’s milk but this is not a very strong Hadith and was classed as weak by Al-Albani. Even if it is Sahih and authentic the meaning is that it is mustahab (recommended or encouraged) to do wudu after drinking camel’s milk but not mandatory But touching things that are impure does not break wudu

Comment: JazakAllah Khair akhi